# How to split compound polygons into convex polygons?

Tags: computational-geometry

Is it possible to split non-convex polygons into convex plygons with Mathematica 9?

For example:

```
pts={{-5, 29.6537}, {-4, 16.3031}, {-3, 13.8614}, {-2, 9.22332}, {-1, 
  6.89646}, {0, 6.76047}, {1, 9.20436}, {2, 6.65919}, {3, 
  18.2084}, {4, 18.9102}, {5, 31.6521}}
```

[image]

Comment: You may Triangulate it!

Comment: This is not unique. Have you tried dividng it into triangles?

Comment: As noted, even the triangulation isn't unique... ;)

Comment: See [my answer to the MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60212/partitioning-a-polygon-into-convex-parts/60215#60215), "Partitioning a polygon into convex parts."  There is a relatively easy algorithm (Hertel-Mehlhorn) superior to triangulation for most shapes.

Comment: http://www.dma.fi.upm.es/docencia/trabajosfindecarrera/programas/geometriacomputacional/PiezasConvex/algoritmo_i.html is a very nice exposition of both a triangulation algorithm and the Hertel-Mehlhorn algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In V9, hidden in `` Graphics`Mesh` `` is the `PolygonTriangulate` function...

```
pts = {{-5, 29.6537}, {-4, 16.3031}, {-3, 13.8614}, {-2, 9.22332}, {-1, 6.89646},
 {0, 6.76047}, {1, 9.20436}, {2, 6.65919}, {3, 18.2084}, {4, 18.9102}, {5, 31.6521}};

Graphics[
 GraphicsComplex[
  pts,
  {EdgeForm[{Thick, Gray}],
   LightRed,
   Polygon@Graphics`Mesh`PolygonTriangulate[pts]}
  ], Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

---

**V10 update**

While the OP specifically asks about V9, it is worth pointing out a more current solution, [`DiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html).  It has a tendency to add points, which are not strictly necessary. [`MaxCellMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxCellMeasure.html) can control the size of the triangles to some extent.

```
Show[
 DiscretizeRegion[
  Polygon[pts], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> Infinity}],
 Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can get the same result using [`TriangulateMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TriangulateMesh.html) and  [`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeRegion.html).